# Command line to filter the logs

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I'm finding a way to filter the following format

```
2015-11-02,012111,maxis,32771,awesome is the new orange.
```

Is there any linux or command like to filter by `,` so that the output after i grep/awk or find the output will just be

```
32771
```

when i filter the following log, possible?

Comment: Will that number always be at the same index? If so, you should be able to make an awk command that treats the comma as a delimiter and extract it

Comment: @Mike, sadly its' not the same index. It ranges from 32000-33000. So i want to capture how many incoming transmission

Comment: @Jeeca Suriyaa sorry I should have been more clear. I meant would the value always be beside the third comma? If so, the answer below pretty much has a solution for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Mike is right, try this:

```
awk -F"," '{print $4}' <logfile>
```

awk command processes the file line by line

-F argument filters the line by the character set next to it. In this case ",".

print directive prints the field number selected by $. In this case you are looking for field number 4.

The last argument is the file name.

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F ',' '{print $4}' <<<'2015-11-02,012111,maxis,32771,awesome is the new orange.'
32771
```

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations.

Comment: maybe to you and the asker. But keep in mind, that you are not alone. Just explain why your answer solve the issue, where was the mistake, what do you use to solve the issue, etc... I recommend you to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer carefully